# Delete text in cell subject to Worksheet_Change

Tags: excel, vba

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Not (Application.Intersect(Target, Range("C1:C3,G1:G3,L1:L3,P1:P3")) _
      Is Nothing) Then
        With Target
            If Not .HasFormula Then
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                .Value = UCase(.Value)
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

The program automatically capitalizes the area I want. However if I press delete, if I mistyped, it errors out. Backspace works.

Comment: Thats because you have not placed a "check" to see if target has a value of "empty" or lenght of 0, when you delete stuff it tries to do the UCase on Nothing and it crashes. Backspace works because it doesnt trigger the "change" until you move away from the cell. Delete triggers the Change.

Comment: How would I go about doing that, extremely new to programing.

Comment: If Not .HasFormula AND Len(.Value) > 0 Then

Comment: I assumed i needed to replace "If Not .HasFormula Then" with that code however it is currently erroring out still. or am I mistaken..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a safer way to approach what you want to do - it makes sure if you try to update multiple cells it will not crash:

```vb
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim c As Range, rng As Range
    
    Set rng = Application.Intersect(Target, _
                  Me.Range("C1:C3,G1:G3,L1:L3,P1:P3"))
    
    If Not rng Is Nothing Then 'any cells of interest updated?
        Application.EnableEvents = False
        For Each c In rng.Cells 'check each cell
            If Not c.HasFormula Then
                c.Value = UCase(c.Value)
            End If
        Next c
        Application.EnableEvents = True
    End If
End Sub
```

BTW I was not seeing any errors with your posted code when selecting a cell and pressing Delete...

Comment: thanks this worked, also my code had issues if i had deleted a cell full of text. if it did not have text it would not error out (see the cells specified)